# Using variables in Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I am looking to use variables to find a range as well as then use those to activate a selection.

Here is the code I have:

```
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer

first = (ActiveCell.Row + 1)
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Last = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)
Range(("J" & first) : ("J" & last)).Select
```

However, I am getting a syntax error on this in Excel VBA 2010.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Range syntax is Range("A1:B2") so you will need to modify your code to:

```
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer

first = (ActiveCell.Row + 1)
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Last = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)
Range("J" & first & ":" & "J" & Last).Select
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works perfect.  Next part is how to use that in formula- posting on that now.