# Excel - Variable in Range

Tags: vba, excel

The variable tablelength counts how many items are in a table of mine. I want to select my entire table, but it varies in sizes so my range has to include a variable. I've googled a lot and searched this site ([Using variables in Excel range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175396/using-variables-in-excel-range) <- that method looked promising but didn't work). Below is a snippet of my code, but includes everything that is relevant.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim shSource As Worksheet
 Dim shDest As Worksheet
 Dim tablelength As Integer

 Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 'here comes some code that determines the value of tablelength, which is 8 in this case
 shDest.Range("L" & "4" & ":" & "M" & tablelength).Select
End Sub
```

I appreciate the help.

edit: the debugger highlights the shDest.Range code.

Comment: What's the problem? I get what you are trying to do, but it's not clear to me what problem you're running into.

Comment: OK. Sometimes, tablelength = 3, somtimes tablelength = 8, sometimes tablelength = 33 etc. L4 is a constant cell in my table (the cornerstone), and I want to select the entire table but it's size varies, so doing the good 'ol Range("L4:M33") and so on, is out of the question. I need the second "cell" in my Range function to be a variable but whenever I try using the code above I get this error:http://imgur.com/ELCVY1o

Comment: Does the tablelength variable have a value before running the shDest.Range... part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need tablelength variable somewhere else in the code, you could try using:

```
shDest.Range("L4").CurrentRegion.Select
```

CurrentRegion.Select will select all cells starting from "L4" until it reaches a blank row and column, so providing your tables are surrounded by blank cells this should select the whole table regardless of the size

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(10, 4)).Select
```

Taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308

The first parameter to Cells is the row and the second is the column as a number.

So for you it would look something like this:

```
shDest.Range(Cells(4, 12), Cells(tablelength, 13)).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a proper Table on the spreadsheet, and not just cells formatted to look like a table, you can directly refer to the 'live' size of the table in your code without jumping through all these hoops.

In your VBA code,

1. The 'Table' is referred to as a `ListObject`
2. You can declare a new `ListObject`, and look up its DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

This should work:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim Tabl As ListObject
    Set Tabl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    MsgBox Tabl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

You can also set a range variable to refer to the 'Data' range. You need to use the following code.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
```

Now Rng.Cell(1,1) or Rng.Range("A1") refers to the top left cell of the data body and so on and so forth...